# HTML mail in Microsoft Teams channel is showing in raw format instead the correct format

Tags: html, powershell, html-table, sendmail, microsoft-teams

I am trying to send an HTML mail that contains table tags to Outlook and Microsoft Teams channel from Powershell. The format is correct once it is received in Outlook. But in teams, it is showing in raw format. How can I format it to show correctly in Teams? I have searched on many web pages, but couldn't get any solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you please share the piece of code what you are trying?